# loading CSS module with next.js

Tags: javascript, css, next.js

I use 'react-multi-carousel' in my react app and I`m a little confused about styling it with css, especially in ssr. It works pretty good if I use @zeit/next-css, and import 'react-multi-carousel/lib/styles.css' in my carousel component file.
But as I understand from [Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-2) it have built-In CSS module support. I tried to implement it without @zeit/next-css by importing 'react-multi-carousel/lib/styles.css' in _app.js. Well, it works good on client side, but when I switch off java script the layout totally breaks.
Is there any way to import package styles as a module?

Comment: if you disabled javascript of course everything will be broken. you should  understand first how SSR  and Next.js works.  Only first Html is SSR renderend along with all the necessay javascript.

Comment: Each generated HTML is associated with minimal JavaScript code necessary for that page. When a page is loaded by the browser, its JavaScript code runs and makes the page fully interactive. (This process is called hydration.)

Comment: @Nico, thanx for your answer to my newbie question. But still I don`t understand why in SSR layout is ok if I use @zeit/next-css and if it's possible to to import the CSS from a npm packages without @zeit/next-css

Comment: Are you testing in development(`next dev`) or production(`next build && next start`)?

Comment: @Hangindev I run the app in development

Comment: Could you check if this happens in production as well?

Comment: @Hangindev, it loks like there`s no broken layout im production, looks the same with or without JS

Comment: Then it should ease your concern? I believe during development, JS is necessary since Next.js supports styles hot reloading as you edit them. In production, all CSS files will be automatically concatenated into a single minified `.css` file. [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-a-global-stylesheet)

Comment: @Hangindev, that explains. Thank you!